# Valores de um formulario para outro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, formulário

No `index.html` terá um pré-formulário com nome, e-mail, cidade e UF.

Vou precisar pegar esses dados e jogar para outro formulário que estará em outro arquivo html.

Tenho uma certa noção em jQuery, mas gostaria de saber se vou ter que usar ajax ou sessionStorage ou alguma outra coisa.

Comment: Isso não será possível se você quer pegar os dados digitais no formulário1.html e querer ir para o formulario2.html e esses dados estarem lá. Para isso, você precisará usar uma linguagem backend e um banco de dados, como o PHP e MySQL.

Comment: Oloco sera?? já pesquisei sobre mas achei legal postar aqui e ver se achava uma ajuda...vou pesquisar mais

Comment: Se fosse na mesma página até dava pra dar um jeito com o jQuery, mas como você vai sair do formulario 1 e ir para o 2, então terá que usar algo que guarde os dados e exiba em outra página. O melhor jeito seria uma linguagem backend com banco de dados. Uma saída talvez para você, pode ser o uso de cookies, mas não acho uma boa.

Comment: sim o uso de coockie, por que não vou utilizar essas dados ao ponto de criar um banco de dados, o usuário ai preencher os dados e clicar em cadastrar, vai abrir outra pagina com um formulário maior e mais completo e já estará preenchido com os dados do formulário anterior, nao vou mais usar esses dados, então prefiro que eles sejam apagados com o cache... estou estudadando sobre  localStorage para recuperar dados em outra pagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já resolvi o problema, e usei o localStorage

```
$('.link-enviar').on('click', function(e){
  var nome1 = $('#nome1').val();
  var email1 = $('#email1').val();
  var cidade1 = $('#cidade1').val();
  var uf1 = $('#uf1').val();

  localStorage.setItem('nome',nome1);
  localStorage.setItem('email',email1);
  localStorage.setItem('cidade',cidade1);
  localStorage.setItem('uf',uf1);
});

$(function(){
  var nome = localStorage.getItem('nome');
  var email = localStorage.getItem('email');
  var cidade = localStorage.getItem('cidade');
  var uf = localStorage.getItem('uf');
  $('#empresa').val(nome);
  $('#email').val(email);
  $('#cidade').val(cidade);
  $('#uf').val(uf);
})'
```

Desta maneira eu fiz um evento de click, onde se pega os valores dos formularios, jogando para o `localStorage`.

Logo apos eu fiz uma função anonima que executa junto com a página, colocando os valores do `localStorage` nos formulários. Deu certinho, obrigado a quem quis ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Podes experimentar isso

*1º Formulário : formA.html*

```
<body>
    <form action="formB.html" method="get">
      Name: <input type="text" name="nome">
      <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="PAGINA B &raquo;">
    </form>
</body>
```

*2º Formulário : formB.html*

```
<body>
    <form action="processar.php" method="post">
      Nome: <input type="text" name="nome">
      Idade: <input type="text" name="idade">
      <input type="submit" value="SALVAR DADOS">
    </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var Field=query.split("=");
       document.getElementById("nome").value = Field[1];
   </script>
</body>
```

Aí podes usar uma expressão regular para remover os `+` da expressão.

Outra opção seriam talvez as funcionalidades do *HTML5*, as `localStorage` ou `sessionStorage` que é menos permanente:

***Parte 1 : A.html***

```
<form action="B.html" onsubmit="return validar(this)" method="post">
Nome: <input type="text" name="fnome">
<input type="submit" value="PAGINA B &raquo;">
</form>

<script>
function validar(form){
    if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined'){
        if(form["fnome"].value != ""){
            sessionStorage.setItem('nome', form["fnome"].value);
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('Preencha o campo');
        }
    } else {
        alert('O navegador nao suporta storage');
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

***Parte 2 : B.html***

```
<form action="validar.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fnome">
Idade: <input type="text" name="fidade">
<input type="submit" value="Salvar">
</form>

<script>
if(typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined'){
    var form = document.querySelector("form");
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('nome')){
        form["fnome"].value = sessionStorage.getItem('nome');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            if(form["fnome"].value != "" && form["fidade"].value > 0){
                alert('Dados digitados:\n\nNome: ' + form["fnome"].value + "\nIdade: " + form["fidade"].value + "\n\nA enviar para servidor...");
                sessionStorage.clear();
                this.submit();
            } else {
                alert("Preencha os campos em branco");
            }
            return false;
        });
    } else {
        form["fnome"].value = "sem nome";
    }
} else {
    alert('O navegador nao suporta storage');
}
</script>
```

> - *[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)* deixa de existir assim que se reinicia o navegador.
> - *[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)* cria dados persistentes.
>
> Podes também ver o primeiro exemplo no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091596/how-to-pass-parameters-between-forms-in-html).